# I want to use multiple functions in one formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I have several grades to use for evaluation: 76-100=VG, 51-75=G, 26-50=F, and 0-25=P.

How to make a formula for the total score to reflect the above evaluations?

Comment: Doesn't make sense. Post few sample data as text table then show your desired output and explain in brief your logic. So that we can convert that logic to excel formula.

Answer (score 3):

You can use vlookup for this. If you don't request exact match, then it will find the first number less than or equal to the number you ask it to look up.

To make it concrete:

If your excel sheet is set up as below:
[image]

Then in cell C2, you can enter the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,$F$2:$G$5,2)
```

You may drag this formula down. It will produce the letter grades as displayed above.

Answer (score 2):

Simple value answer is:

```
=IF(A2>=76,"VG",IF(A2>=51,"G",IF(A2>=26,"F","P")))
```

More complex but double checks both ends:

```
=IF(A2>=76,"VG",IF(AND(A2<=75,A2>=51),"G",IF(AND (A2<=51,A2>=26),"F","P")))
```

Comment: Much longer than vlookup() above and harder to edit - the table is easy to expand.

Comment: Asked specifically "to use multiple functions in one formula" in which nested if statement is specifically how you do that. And/Or() commands are other tools you can use to accomplish the task.  I would say VLookup is longer due to needing comparison chart, but just trying to give more tools. Learning/Education is what this is all about. (Plus I got the F & P correct settings) but I messed up by not using < instead of <=51.